# React input setState default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Is there a chance I can define the default input values from the `setState` hook in React? This dynamic default value should be set in the input field and changeable.

```js
const {
  email = '',
  phoneNumber = '' // <- The default value I want to use
} = authUser || {};

const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
  fullName: '',
  email: '',
  phoneNumber, // <- Define the default value here?
  topic: ''
});

const handleFormChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setFormValues({ ...formValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

<input
  className=""
  id="phoneNumber"
  name="phoneNumber"
  type="tel"
  placeholder={ t('enterPhone') }
  onChange={ handleFormChange }
/>
```

Solution:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (phoneNumber) {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, phoneNumber });
  }
}, [authUser]);
```

Comment: I have used the `<input defaultValue={phoneNumber} />`; however, is there any more supported approach?

Comment: your code already does that!

Comment: `phoneNumber,` is short for `phoneNumber: phoneNumber,` which means the initial value is already the const's from further up. Please clarify what the issue is.

Comment: @ChrisG exactly, but the `formValues` values are empty through all component lifecycle

Comment: Because they're empty to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, so authUser doesn't have a phoneNumber I guess. Or it's empty.

Comment: @Terry nope, this is the default value that is changed later?

Comment: @ChrisG the number is there

Comment: What number? There is no number to begin with: you literally instantiate it with an empty string. Unless `authUser` is truthy. Is that what you're referring to? That the phone number in `authUser` isn't showing up?

Comment: @Terry I need to set the `phoneNumber` from the `authUser` as the default state value, or use the empty string if it is not defined

Comment: And how is your `authUser` object looking like? Is its value being asynchronously set?

Comment: @Terry yes, this is the async value coming from another hook

Comment: Which means it's probably null or {} until that hook completes, so you need to use a useEffect callback and set the phoneNumber in there

Comment: @ChrisG any example on that?

Comment: @ChrisG the `useEffect` hook also has no significant result

Comment: @ChrisG I am asking about the solution, not the docs reference, right? please do not spam here if you have no adequate tips. thanks

Comment: If the solution is in the docs, the question doesn't belong here :/

Comment: @ChrisG, no, it is not. See the updated `useEffect` code, which does not work either. It updates the state but not the input field value...

Comment: If `authUser` is the result of a hook, you need to put that in the dependencies array. Then check if it has a phoneNumber and if so, update the state.

Comment: Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-buck-ljd0oc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG please see the updated code. But this still has no effect on the input component, while the state updates as expected :c

Comment: Your input needs `value={formValues.phoneNumber}` or it'll stay blank (this was part of the problem from the start btw)

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your patience in discovering the issue's origins! Much appreciate it!!!! :)))))